# Showing functional has Minimizier

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, nonlinear-optimization

Given the functional

$$J(x,x'):=\int_0^1 x^2+x'^2+(x^2-1)^2 dt$$

show that a mimimizer exists in $H^1([0,1])$.

Obviously J is bounded from below. For $\{u_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subset H^1(\Omega)$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} J(u_n,u_n'):=\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1 u_n^2+u_n'^2+(u_n^2-1)^2 dt=  \int_0^1 \lim_{n \to \infty} (u_n^2+u_n'^2+(u_n^2-1)^2 )dt  \overbrace{=}^? J(u,u')$$, so J ist continuous? 
How can a convergent subsequence in a minimizing sequence guaranteed? Hints are very much appreciated.

Comment: $J$ is coercive on $H^1$, hence minimizing sequence is bounded. use the compactness of the embedding $H^1\hookrightarrow L^2$ to obtain convergence

Comment: Thanks. Whats the best way to show coercive, especially $(x^2-1)^2 \ge c \|u\|_L^2$

Comment: Observe that $J$=$H^1$-norm plus something nonnegative